# NodeJS eth-lightwallet doesn't allow different bitcore-lib versions among submodules

Tags: node.js

Module eth-lightwallet and its' dependencies have some issue with bitcore-lib version guard. I noticed that some of them have version 0.15 and other 0.14. Do you have any solution to this problem? Error that I receive is presented below.

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { var Module;if(!Module)Module=(typeof Module!=="undefined"?Module:null)||{};var moduleOverrides={};for(var key in Module){if(Module.hasOwnProperty(key)){moduleOverrides[key]=Module[key]}}var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB=typeof window==="object";var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER=typeof importScripts==="function";var ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE=typeof process==="object"&&typeof require==="function"&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER;var ENVIRONMENT_IS_SHELL=!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE&&!ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER;if(ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE){if(!Module["print"])Module["print"]=function print(x){process["stdout"].write(x+"\n")};if(!Module["printErr"])Module["printErr"]=function printErr(x){process["stderr"].write(x+"\n")};var nodeFS=require("fs");var nodePath=require("path");Module["read"]=function read(filename,binary){filename=nodePath["normalize"](filename);var ret=nodeFS["readFileSync"]

Error: More than one instance of bitcore-lib found. Please make sure to require bitcore-lib and check that submodules do not also include their own bitcore-lib dependency.
    at Object.bitcore.versionGuard (\GitHub\X\node_modules\eth-lightwallet\node_modules\bitcore-mnemonic\node_modules\bitcore-lib\index.js:12:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (\GitHub\X\node_modules\eth-lightwallet\node_modules\bitcore-mnemonic\node_modules\bitcore-lib\index.js:15:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (\GitHub\X\node_modules\eth-lightwallet\node_modules\bitcore-mnemonic\lib\mnemonic.js:3:15)

Process finished with exit code 7`
```

Answer (score 1):

**Full proof solution**

*In your main file, set **_bitcore** in **global** to return undefined on every retrieval of its value. _bitcore is not used for anything other than guarding version in **bitcore-lib** .*

```
Object.defineProperty(global, '_bitcore', {
get(){
    return undefined
},
set(){}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided here worked for me: bitpay/bitcore#1454

> Well, this is far from a proper way to solve this issue, but you can
>   get rid of this error by editing file
>
> ~/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.3/lib/node_modules/bitcore/node_modules/insight-api/node_modules/bitcore-lib/index.js
>
> line 7: bitcore.versionGuard = function(version) { Change it to:
>   bitcore.versionGuard = function(version) { return;
>
> I did this and so far no problems.

Answer (score 0):

This error causes of version confliction.
I fixed this error by changing the version of

`bitcore-lib` and `bitcore-mnemonic/bitcore-lib` by `^0.15.0`

(which `bitcore-mnemonic/bitcore-lib` is `^0.16.0`).

Then `npm install` again.